# SimpleCartJS - How to get all items in cart?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I am trying to integrate SimpleScriptJS v3 in a Force.com visualforce page.
I am able to query products from Salesforce and show them using SimpleCartJS class params.
Products are correctly added to the cart and empty, remove, increment and decrement links works perfectly.
I dont need to checkout to PayPal, google, etc. What I need is to create records into some object directly on salesforce when user clics on "ckeckout" button, so I need to get all items in cart in order to iterate and and use info to create records in Salesforce.

This is my visualforce page:

```
<script src="{!$Resource.ShoppingCart_SimpleCart_JS}" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="{!$Resource.ShoppingCart_JQuery_JS}" type="text/javascript"/>  

<apex:pageBlock >

    <apex:repeat value="{!existingProducts}" var="wrapper">
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="float:left;padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px" styleClass="simpleCart_shelfItem">
            <apex:image value="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!wrapper.imageId}" width="150" height="150"/>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align:center">
                <apex:outputText value="{!wrapper.product.Name}" styleClass="item_name"/><br/>
                <apex:outputText value="Price: ${!wrapper.price}" styleClass="item_price"/><br/>
                <apex:outputLink value="javascript:;" styleClass="item_add">Add to Cart</apex:outputLink><br/><br/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:repeat>


    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="float:right;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="simpleCart_quantity"></apex:outputPanel>
        items - 
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="simpleCart_total"></apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="simpleCart_items" layout="block"></apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:;" styleClass="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout </apex:outputLink>
        <apex:outputLink value="javascript:;" styleClass="simpleCart_empty"> Empty Cart</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Checkout" action="{!checkout}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>            
</apex:pageBlock>
```

As i said, items are correctly added and shown into the cart (my output panel with the styleClass="simpleCart_items" property).

The question is, how can i put all cart items into an array or something in order to iterate it and use them.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks a lot!!!

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the items array using the SimpleCart object:

```
simpleCart.each(function(item){
    console.log( item.get('quantity') + ' x ' + item.get('name') );
});
```

Alternatively, you can submit the form to a custom script using the .sendForm method.